# Rails - Save JSON keys in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I an using multiple external JSON files and displaying the results on my website.

I want to use the same view for all different files....so I need to be able to insert the params from my database in this view template.

So here are a few scenarios -

```
<% @results[leaderboard][players].first(25).each do |player| %>
   <%= player[player_bio][first_name] + ' ' + player[player_bio][last_name] %>
   <%= player[total] %>
<% end %>

<% @results[leaderboard][players].first(25).each do |player| %>
  <%= player[player_bio][name] %>
  <%= player[total] %>
<% end %>

<% @results[results][leaderboard][players].first(25).each do |player| %>
  <%= player[name] %>
  <%= player[round][game][total] %>
<% end %>
```

So the first line of each example -

```
result = [leaderboard][players]
result = [results][leaderboard][players]
```

I would like to pull the result from the database that will work with both scenarios.

Same with the others -

```
name = player[player_bio][name]
name = player[player_bio][first_name] + ' ' + player[player_bio][last_name]
name = player[name]

total = player[total]
total = player[total]
total = player[round][game][total]
```

So each Event I can save the correct params for that external JSON file.

A couple more notes...

- Unique Events are stored in my database  (Event)
- Each Event has a json file with a totally unique structure that cannot be modifed.
- I have no problem rendering JSON results. External files are stored locally (EventFeed)
- Only One Template View (The point is flexibility with JSON)
- Each Event Feed has a unique params to show the results

Problems -

- Database stores as a string
- Single bracket I can insert a string, but not with params side by side [' '][' ']
- Every JSON file has different levels of depth to get what I need so the html.erb has to be flexible!!

Options -

- I can edit anything EXCEPT the JSON file and they are NEVER the same structure

Maybe?? -

- Can I store the params as a hash then call that hash to the view?

So...

```
@event = Event.find(params[:id])
event_feed = EventFeed.where(event_id: @event).last #External JSON is saved
@results = event_feed.feed #JSON file is saved here
@filter = JsonFilter.where(event_id: @event).last
```

UPDATE***

View -

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <% player_loop.first(25).each do |player| %>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <%= player_name player: @player_name = player %>
        </td>
        <td>
          <%= player_option player: @player_option = player %>
        </td>
        <td class="text-center">
          <%= player_score player: @player_score = player %>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
  </table>
</div>
```

Helper -

```
def player_loop
    if @filter.loop_level == 1
      @results[@filter.loop_one] 
    else @filter.loop_level == 2
      @results[@filter.loop_one][@filter.loop_two]
    end
  end

  def player_name(player_name)
    if @filter.name_level == 1
      @player_name[@filter.name_one]  
    else @filter.name_level == 2
      @player_name[@filter.name_one][@filter.name_two] + ' ' + @player_name[@filter.name_one][@filter.name_three]
    end
  end

  def player_option(player_option)
    if @filter.option_level == 1
      @player_option[@filter.name_one]  
    elsif @filter.option_level == 2
      @player_option[@filter.option_one][@filter.option_two]
    else @filter.option_level == 3
      @player_option[@filter.option_one][@filter.option_two][@filter.option_three]
    end
  end

  def player_score(player_score)
    if @filter.score_level == 1
      @player_score[@filter.score_one]  
    elsif @filter.score_level == 2
      @player_score[@filter.score_one][@filter.score_two]
    else @filter.score_level == 3
      @player_score[@filter.score_one][@filter.score_two][@filter.score_three]
    end
  end
```

So...

The latest update works great :)...not sure if it is the BEST way top do this and would love to be shown that I am doing this WAY too complicated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you simply want to save some JSON object in a column on some table, called `JsonKey`, correct?

If so, check out [ActiveRecord's `serialize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Serialization/ClassMethods.html) ability. With this, you can insert a hash / JSON data directly into a row and retrieve it for use in your views, controllers, etc.

Once you add:

```
serialize :your_json_column, JSON
```

You can simply call `JsonKey.first.your_json_column` and then use the JSON stored in your controller or view.

Comment: Hey @CDub, I don't have a problem with showing results...just flexibility of code. Check out my update and you will see I am using JsonFilter (was JsonKey) table and pulling the html.erb based on assigning an integer so I can change up the JSON view. Hopefully you can see why I am doing this better now since you see a working answer! I would love some critic to do it a better way!